# How can i set access-control with LDAP use java api

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, jndi, acl

There are standard Java API's for LDAP  from Sun.
now i use these to operate  Active Directory.
now i can create user account、create computer with java api.
But how can I  grant authorization user&group to join a computer to an AD domain when i new a computer account?

i  know openLDAP can do it [:Access Control](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html)
but how can i do with java api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Granting authorization** is not discrib in any LDAP RFC. This part is proprietary.

In OpenLDAP *Access Control List* (ACL) is established by a kind of filter.

In SUN Directory (Nowdays Oracle one) ACLs are established by attributes.

In Active Directory granting authorization is done using internal in the same proprietary maner as in the NFTS file system.

The thing you can do is to execute an external program like [DSACLS.EXE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490872.aspx) see [Dsacls Examples](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739515%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Another solution should be to map COM ADSI objects into Java [this](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/support/com/doc/#other_examples/Creating_an_NT_User_via_ADSI_from_Java.htm) may help you (or not).